# How to create custom tag's archive page for custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

When i add custom tag to custom post type, the archive page doesn't work.

taxonomy-tags.php has been added,here is some of my code:

```php
function create_taxonomies_tag() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( '新标签', 'taxonomy 名称' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( '新标签', 'taxonomy 单数名称' ),
            'search_items'      => __( '搜索新标签' ),
            'all_items'         => __( '所有新标签' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( '该新标签的上级分类' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( '该新标签的上级分类：' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( '编辑新标签' ),
            'update_item'       => __( '更新新标签' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( '添加新的新标签' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( '新的标签' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( '新标签' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => false,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => tags ),
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'tags', array('site'), $args );
    }
```

what should i  do to fix it? please help me,thanks

Comment: Isn't the taxonomy "tags" already registered by core wordpress? shouldn't it be a unique name

Comment: For post tag, `post_tag` is used. Not `tags`.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Toolset Types plugin](https://toolset.com/), can give you some guide about this and help enabling what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When i click 'Save Changes' button at xxx/wp-admin/options-permalink.php page, then it works